# PHP Arrays inside of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I dont know what to call this, but I exploded the each of the values of a pre-existing array to create another array with each of the exploded values on a new array identifier ([0],[1],etc). But for some reason it created something like this and its getting hard to handle the values.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => mail1@provider.com
        [1] => password1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => mail2@provider.com
        [1] => password2
    )
```

How do I make each of those values have their own identifier? Help please..

Comment: What do you mean "own identifier"? You can easily access them via `$data[0][1]` e.g.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could have more than one identifier..

Comment: read about multidimensional arrays. you'll figure it out.

Comment: Yep, [manual](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) covers this as well

Comment: this is a multidimensional array with key-value pairs, the keys being numerical indexes, i believe you mean to say "key" instead of "identifier"...

Comment: no, an element can only have one index (what you mean by identifier). This can be a `string` or an `integer`

Comment: Welcome to data structures my friend :-)

Comment: It is only a multidimensional array.  No need to fret. They can actually be quite helpful depending on the situation.  If you want to make arrays with non-numerical keys, look into associative arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [multidimensional array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp), don't let it scare you off, they're **better** to deal with than an array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => mail1@provider.com
    [1] => password1
    [2] => mail2@provider.com
    [3] => password2
    )
```

What you do instead of accessing those values directly (or within your loop) is create another loop around it:

```
foreach($array as $current) {
    foreach($current as $subarray) {
        list($email, $password) = $subarray;
        echo $email . ': ' . $password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea I just did something just like that a second ago. Loops are great. Thanks dude. c:

Comment: no worries, have fun with structured data - it makes your life a whole lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about `foreach`? If so you can try

```
foreach($arrOut as $arrIn) {
    foreach($inArr as $key => $val)
        echo $key . ': ' . $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```